# Run php script by docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, docker-compose

I am getting started with docker. I want to run simple php code:

```
<?php 
    echo 'Hello World !';
?>
```

I have docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:latest
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
          - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
          - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
          - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
          - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
        volumes:
          - ./public_html/:/var/www/html
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "32823:22"
        links:
          - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - PMA_USER=root
          - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
          - mysql:db
        depends_on:
          - mysql

volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false
```

Structure is:

```
-app
  -public_html
     -index.php
  -docker-compose.yml
```

I run this configuration by docker-compose up -d
The problem is that I enter localhost on the web browser I have:
[image]

Any suggestions how can I run my PHP script?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you bash into the web container and verify the file is where you want it?

Comment: What is "this"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase "this" means his docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have entered to bash and enter to /var/www/html and here I have my index.php with that code.

Comment: Does the Apache config for the container specify that `/var/html/www` is the home directory for the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should use the right volume settings see https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-apache-dev.html#php-development-environment-variables

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:latest
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
          - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
          - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
          - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
          - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
        volumes:
          - ./public_html/:/app
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "32823:22"
        links:
          - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - PMA_USER=root
          - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
          - mysql:db
        depends_on:
          - mysql

volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false
```